# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named customerManager

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I am new to JPA & Hibernate. After reading some online materials I now understand what Hibernate is and how it can be used with JPA.

Now, I am trying to run this [JPA & Hibernate tutorial](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/04/02/jpa-hibernate-with-oracle-on-eclipse.html). I've done everything they mention in this tutorial.

I don't have Oracle DB, only MySQL. So I made some changes to `persistence.xml` using my understanding of JPA & Hibernate (I don't know if it's correct or not... Seems to me it is.)

Here is my `persistence.xml`

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="customerManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Customer</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/general"/>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

But I don't seem to get the output they describe. It's giving me:

```
Customer id before creation:null
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence     provider for EntityManager named customerManager
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)
 at CustomerDAO.create(CustomerDAO.java:8)
 at CustomerDAO.main(CustomerDAO.java:22)
```

**Any suggestions will be appreciated.**

**Update:**

I have made the changes that are asked to done. But, still getting the asme error lines!!!

They didnt mentioned anything about **orm.xml** in that tutorial. may it be a problem causer!!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `persistence.xml` is not valid and the `EntityManagerFactory` can't get created. It should be:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="customerManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Customer</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/general"/>
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

(Note how the `<property>` elements are closed, they shouldn't be nested)

**Update:** I went through the tutorial and you will also have to change the `Id` generation strategy when using MySQL (as MySQL doesn't support sequences). I suggest using the `AUTO` strategy (defaults to IDENTITY with MySQL). To do so, remove the `SequenceGenerator` annotation and change the code like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TAB_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", precision=0)
    private Long customerId = null;

   ...
}
```

This should help.

PS: you should also provide a `log4j.properties` as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still giving the same error message. Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named customerManager

Comment: Again thanks for your update. I added that log4j.jar in the lib folder as they said in the tutorial. What is the way to initialize it?

Comment: @MaRaVan You need to put a `log4j.properties` on the classpath. The tutorial provides an example.

Answer (score 27):

Just for completeness. There is another situation causing this error:

> missing META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
>   file.

For Hibernate, it's located in `hibernate-entitymanager-XXX.jar`, so, if `hibernate-entitymanager-XXX.jar` is not in your classpath, you will got this error too.

This error message is so misleading, and it costs me hours to get it correct.

See [JPA 2.0 using Hibernate as provider - Exception: No Persistence provider for EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808320/jpa-2-0-using-hibernate-as-provider-exception-no-persistence-provider-for-ent).

Comment: Same applies to Eclipselink and other JPA implementations.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem today. My persistence.xml was in the wrong location. I had to put it in the following path:

```
project/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

Comment: Tnx. I put my "persistence.xml" in wrong location. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue. I realised that I was using the Wrong provider class in persistence.xml

For Hibernate it should be

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

And for EclipseLink it should be

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use Hibernate 5.2.10.Final, you should change

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

to

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

in your persistence.xml

According to [Hibernate 5.2.2: No Persistence provider for EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410183/hibernate-5-2-2-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven you may have **both** `src/{main,test}/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`. This is a common setup: test your JPA code with h2 or Derby and deploy it with PostgreSQL or some other full DBMS. If you're using this pattern, do make sure the two files have **different** unit names, else some versions of the `Persistence` class will try to load BOTH (because of course your test-time CLASSPATH includes both classes and test-classes); this will cause conflicting definitions of the persistence unit, resulting in the dreaded annoying message that we all hate so much!

Worse: this may "work" with some older versions of e.g., Hibernate, but fail with current versions. Worth getting it right anyway...

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but I got the same issue and fixed it switching **schemalocation** into **schemaLocation** in the **persistence.xml** file (line 1).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error , for me the issue was there was a space in the absolute path of the persistance.xml , removal of the same helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when I was trying to get JPA entity manager configured in Tomcat 8. First I has an issue with the SystemException class not being found and hence the entityManagerFactory was not being  created. I removed the hibernate entity manager dependency and then my entityManagerFactory was not able to lookup for the persistence provider. After going thru a lot of research and time got to know that hibernate entity manager is must to lookup for some configuration. Then put back the entity manager jar and then added JTA Api as a dependency and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

my experience tells me that missing persistence.xml,will generate the same exception too.

i caught the same error msg today when i tried to run a jar package packed by ant.

when i used jar tvf to check the content of the jar file, i realized that "ant" forgot to pack the persistnece.xml for me.

after I manually repacked the jar file ,the error msg disappered.

so i believe maybe you should try simplely putting META-INF under src directory and placing your persistence.xml there.