# JPA 2.0 using Hibernate as provider - Exception: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven

I'm trying to set up a simple jpa 2.0 project by following the information in the Hibernate EntityManager [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#architecture-javase). I've been on this for hours now, but no matter what I do I always get this exception when I try to create a EntityManagerFactory:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named manager1
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
    at se.mycomp.UserTest.main(UserTest.java:9)
```

I've found quite a few similar questions regarding this exception, but no solutions that I am able to get to work. What am I doing wrong here?

***directory structure***

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── se
    │   │       └── mycomp
    │   │           ├── UserTest.java
    │   │           └── domain
    │   │               └── User.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── META-INF
    │       │   └── persistence.xml
    │       └── log4j.properties
    └── test
        └── java
```

my ***persistence.xml***

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>se.mycomp.domain.User</class> 
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my ***pom.xml***

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>se.lil.tryjpa</groupId>
<artifactId>try-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <hibernate-core.version>3.6.4.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <mysql-connector-java.version>5.1.16</mysql-connector-java.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.6.1</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- HIBERNATE DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***UserTest.java***

```
public class UserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Maybe you miss the Provider class or one of its dependencies in your pom.xml dependencies?

The link you give to the hibernate docs says that you should also add

```xml
<project ...>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

to your pom.xml

Comment: Not embarrassing at all, that error message is singularly useless (applies to a whole host of issues).

Comment: I'd like to add that this dependency should replace the `hibernate-core` one, not just be added alongside, because it in fact already includes `hibernate-core`. See the list of Maven dependencies on Hibernate [downloads page](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/). They explicitly say that `for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core`.

Comment: I was not using maven, so solved this by adding the hibernate-entity-manager.jar ( found in the dist\lib\optional\jpa directory in hibernate 5.5.2 zip ), and then by downloading and adding jta-1.1.jar

Comment: `hibernate-entitymanager` is now integrated into `hibernate-core`

Answer (score 2):

persistence.xml is meant to be present in META-INF directory and META-INF is meant to be present in the classpath of the application which is src folder.

As per your folder structure its present in resource folder, try moving it to classpath it sholud work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem solved using the dependencies below and the following provider:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

is LATEST doesn't work as Version for you, you can use 
1.0.1.Final for hibernate-jpa-2.0-api
and 5.2.5.Final for hibernate-entitymanager

Also, in persistence.xml, don't forget hbm2dll.auto properties (this was one issue I've spent some time figuring out)

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Then make a maven clean install