# JPA persistence provider

Tags: persistence, openjpa, provider

I have a problem with my jpa project.

Already found this thread:

[JPA: configure persistence provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001344/jpa-configure-persistence-provider)

My persistence.xml is at:

C:\workspace\DevWorkSample\src\META-INF

so this seems to be correct.

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="CustomerQuery">
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <class>myjpa.CustomerAcct</class>
        <!-- exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes -->
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.LockTimeout" value="30000" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.TransactionIsolation" value="read-committed" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="none" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order" />

             <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="DB URL"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="Driver Name"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="userid"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="password"/>

            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Errors:

1.

```
 An error occurred in the com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the CustomerQuery persistence unit. The following error occurred: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.
```

2.

`For the [com.ibm.devworks.Deposit] servlet, com.ibm.devworks.Deposit servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/com.ibm.devworks.Deposit/emf reference.  The exception message was: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1642995 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details`.

What do I have to change to fix this?

Comment: Did you get any fix for the above problem.
I am also facing the same issue. Post the solution if you have any.

Comment: No, sorry. I have just created a new project and then it worked...