# spring "persistence.xml" file location

Tags: spring, jpa

Developing web application under STS 3.4.0.RELEASE (Spring). I have working JPA example under Eclipse Juno and want to port it as part of Spring application. I have to copy persistence.xml file. Where should it be located exactly?

So far I get "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ..." which may be related to location or may be not.

Is there a need for "provider" element and if so what should be the value? (It worked fine under Eclipse without that element).

Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your persistence.xml is not valid and the EntityManagerFactory can't get created

Refer this similar question [Cause of this Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739387/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanage)

Hope it helps..

Comment: yes, one of many advice in that thread helped to move on. Is JPA in Spring implemented above Hibernate? It pulled several Hibernate classes. Current situation:
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: JPA] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:378)at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(

Answer (score 0):

The `persistence.xml` file should be placed in `META-INF/persistence.xml` in your classpath.