# No Persistence provider for "EntityManager" named "firstOne" Java

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven

I'm using persistense api to connect to database

this is pom.xml dependendcies

```
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
```

persistense.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="firstOne">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">tauren993</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

    <mapping class="Employee" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml and persistense.xml are stored project/META-INF folder and I'm getting error on

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("firstOne");
```

Stack Trace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named firstOne
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named firstOne
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
 at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Answer (score 1):

In your persistance-unit "firstOne" you should include the provider. say like below:

```
<persistence-unit name="firstOne">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

Comment: included but the same problem

Comment: Can you update your question with the modified persistance.xml?

Comment: I Update it as you said

Comment: Can you check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739387/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanage?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named and see if your problem is related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the entities declaration. If you're in JAVA EE context ensure that you have some classes annotated as entities in your project. Otherwise, in a JAVA SE context you must define the provider as thiyaga said  (see the [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html/hibernate-gsg-tutorial-jpa.html)) and specify the entities as below :

```
<persistence-unit name="OrderManagement">
    [...]
    <jar-file>MyOrderApp.jar</jar-file>
     or / and 
    <class>com.widgets.Order</class>
    <class>com.widgets.Customer</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Moreover,

You should use JPA 2 if you can

You doesn't need anymore the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, just put directly your properties in the `<properties>` element of the `persitence.xml`file, ensure that the hibernate properties are well prefixed with `hibernate`.

Comment: You should see an error in logs on server startup during the persistence context initialization

Comment: In SE context you can add `hibernate.archive.autodetection`property  as described by Pascal Thivent here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780341/do-i-need-class-elements-in-persistence-xml