# Hibernate: Could not open connection

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to connect to Oracle by Hibernate. But I get following Exception:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy239.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
```

I use following configuration:

```
map.put("hibernate.connection.username", "user");
map.put("hibernate.connection.password", "user"); 
map.put("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.11:1521/rch"); 
map.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
map.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"); 
map.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"); 
map.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "100"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "1"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "300"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "0"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "3600"); 
map.put("hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout", "60000"); 
map.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
```

Each time I invoke the singleResult-method I get this Exception. A programm, that uses the same JDBC-driver, but not hibernate, can easily connect with the same data (url and credentials).

Comment: Have a look here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739387/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanage

Comment: Please recheck your connection URL, SID should be given with a `:` instead of `/` for Oracle THIN driver!

Comment: But "Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.44:1521/rch","zewnsys","zewnsys");" does connect.

Comment: It really looks strange with the slash. I am using a colon for the SID.

Comment: I tried this out (with colon), with the same effect.

Comment: Strange is, that hibernate doesn't make any attempt to contact the oracle-server via network.