# Hibernate 5.2.2: No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate

What has changed between Hibernate 5.1.1 and 5.2.2? If I use 5.2.2 I'll get an error message "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named pu". Exactly the same configuration works with 5.1.1. How should I change my code to get 5.2.2 to work?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jpatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpatest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1209.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

persistence.xml in src/main/resources/META-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="pu" >
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="xxx" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="zzz" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> -->
            <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

creating EntityManager

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
em = factory.createEntityManager();
tx = em.getTransaction();
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The class **org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence** does not exist in the *hibernate-release-5.2.2.Final.zip* bundle file. That's why the provider can't be found, because the class can't (at the project library jars). Instead, I used the class **org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider**, which **CAN** be found at hibernate-core-5.2.2.Final.jar (that comes with hibernate-release-5.2.2.Final.zip bundle), by changing the provider at persistence.xml to **`<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>`**. Doing so, it worked fine! Hope the problem is only this.

Comment: Note the deprecation and replacement at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence.html

Comment: Is it at all possible to specify <Provider> inside EntityManagerFactory bean in xml ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.
I changed version of

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

from 5.3.1.Final to 5.3.6.Final and error disappeared.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. This fixed it. (Deploy on Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simply forgetting to add the `persistence.xml` file to build path causes this problem. Follow the following steps:

1. Right click on `persistence.xml` file.
2. Click on Build Path
3. Add to build path

Then it should work.