# How to use Hibernate 5.2 with JPA 2 in Netbeans 8

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, netbeans

I am using Windows 10 and Netbeans 8.2. I am able to use JPA 2 with Hibenate 4.3.x. Actually Netbeans 8.2 comes with Hibernate 4.3.x. Now i want to use Hibernate 5.2.x. I have downloaded Hibernate 5.2.12 as zip file from this link `http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/`. Then i have imported it into Netbeans. But i am getting the error :

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager`.

[image: Library Directory Structure]

I know it is easy to use with `maven`.

Comment: Have you tried to unzip the archive and add the containing JARs (under lib/required) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have got the solution.

If the zip folder unzipped and all the jars inside the `required` folder imported, it will not work. One of the following errors or both may shown :

[No Persistence provider for EntityManager named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158159/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named)

[Hibernate 5.2.2: No Persistence provider for EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410183/hibernate-5-2-2-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager)

To solve the above problems have to do the following task : 
This line have to add in the `persistence.xml` file :

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

And have to download `classmate-0.8.0.jar`, and have to add it in the class path. This jar can be downloaded from [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadclassmate080jar.htm)

Then have to download the `hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar` file and Have to add it in the class path. The jar can be downloaded from [Here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar)

In the Netbeans there is a default library called `Hibernate 4.3.x(JPA 2.1)`.If you want to change this library, you have to find the installation folder of Neatbeans and the folder where hibernate has kept. 
In windows it may found in :

`C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\modules\ext\hibernate4`

For Linux it may be found in :

`/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/java/modules/ext/hibernate4/`

Then paste the jars from `required` folder (It will be found in downloaded Hibernate folder)  and other jars mentioned above. You may find some jars duplicate. Then you may notice that some jars of hibernate almost with the same name but difference in version. Then delete the jars which has older version name.

Answer (score 0):

one of your dependency file is Zip file . Extract it and the add the Jar instead